# How to find the regression line equation of these two groups of data and draw the scatter diagram and regression line?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

These two sets of data are as follows:

```
v1 = {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06}
v2 = {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4}
Correlation[v1, v2]
```

Take v1 data as the value range of the independent variable x in the regression linear equation, and v2 data as the value range of the dependent variable y in the regression linear equation. The data in v1 and v2 are corresponding according to the order and location

How to find the regression line equation of these two groups of data and draw the scatter diagram and regression line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = Thread@{v1, v2};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}],
 AxesLabel -> {"v1", "v2"}]
```

> [image: lplm]